# Jquery on equivalent in 1.3.2 version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery version 1.3.2 , I just want to know what is the equivalent of "on" in 1.3.2.
I have used live but it giving the error

> > Error Code: 5272 Message: 'this.chartLoad' Type: Javascript Error Description: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined LineNumber: 0 Url: 
> >     appears in firebug .

I want to use on equivalent because my current jquery version is 1.3.2
so what function can i use instead of on

please help...................

Comment: It's .live. but it seems error is something different. 'this' is undefined I guess.

Comment: how did you use .live()

Comment: This is how i used the live()                                                $(pieObj).live({
                    mouseover: function (event) {
                        eval(data.onmouseover);
                        highChart._showchart(chart, event);
                    },
                    mouseout: function (event) {
                        eval(data.onmouseout);
                        highChart._hideChart(event);
                    }
                });

Comment: Seriously, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.bind()` method. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), as of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

Comment: Actually, `on()` can be used as a substitute for `bind()`, `delegate()` or `live()`. It's hard to tell the form the questioner requires without seeing his code.

Comment: Hard to tell really but I based my answer on his/her statement "I just want to know what is the equivalent of "on" in 1.3.2."

Comment: How are you applying the `.bind()` or `.live()` methods? Please show us sample code of the application.

Comment: $(pieObj).bind({
                    mouseover: function (event) {
                        eval(data.onmouseover);
                        highChart._showchart(chart, event);
                    },
                    mouseout: function (event) {
                        eval(data.onmouseout);
                        highChart._hideChart(event);
                    }
                });